# Laravel blade include partial is not parsing html

Tags: html, laravel-5, laravel-blade

I've email template like below

```
@component('mail::message')
# You're invited for APP

<strong>{{ $fromName }}</strong> invited you for App.

{{ $messageBody }}

<?php switch ($type):
    case App\Mail\InviteEmail::TYPE_INVITE_EMAIL:
?>
        @include('emails.partials.invite')
<?php   break;
    case App\Mail\InviteEmail::TYPE_EXPLAINER_EMAIL:
?>
        @include('emails.partials.explainer')
<?php   break;
    case App\Mail\InviteEmail::TYPE_INTRO_EMAIL:
?>
        @include('emails.partials.intro')
<?php   break;
endswitch;
?>
@endcomponent
```

But when its come to action , @include partials are not parsing html code, instead they are rendered inside some "code" tag. Below is output of what I'm getting

[image]

Answer (score 0):

To output HTML you have to escape it ie.

```
{!! $messageBody !!}.
```

See docs:  https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/blade#displaying-data

Comment: ```$messageBody``` works fine already, just need some solution where I include file ``` @include('emails.partials.invite')```

Answer (score 0):

The Markdown is being interpreted as a code block due to indentation before the `@include` ([markdown reference](https://www.markdownguide.org/basic-syntax/#code-blocks)). I had the same issue and found this answer in [this post](https://laravel.io/forum/01-30-2017-54-markdown-email-doesnt-render-html) . To quote the relevant part:

> I've encountered the same today. The problem was that the indentation
>   of the email template file caused markdown to add  tags around
>   stuff, thus escaping it. You can tell whether this is the case by
>   checking the "HTML Source" tab in mailtrap.